# How can I bulk update a collection of recurring contributions to set the next scheduled contribution to a specific date?

Tags: drupal-views, recurring-contributions, civicrm-entity

If you're using the iATS Payments Extension you control the schedules of recurring contribution from within your CiviCRM. You can already edit a given recurring series and change the next scheduled date. Can this be done in bulk?

Answer (score 5):

Since yesterday you can now do that if you're using Drupal! @jackrabbithanna (Mark) added some code to CiviCRM Entity Project, which now exposes civicrm_contribution_recur as an Entity in Drupal so that you can manipulate it in Drupal like any other Entity. Will post some steps/screenshots here:

1. git clone https://github.com/jackrabbithanna/civicrm_entity.git

   - this is fresh - look for it soon on https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity
2. Enable modules: views, views bulk operations (VBO) and CiviCRM Entity
   **-> also Enable the CiviCRM Entity Actions submodule**
3. Clear caches twice!
4. Add a view: Show: Recurring Contributions Profile; you will want it to Format: Show: Fields and Create a page for it.
5. Add Field: Bulk Operations: CiviCRM Contribution Recur

[image]

6. Select Modify Entity Values (as we're going to want to update values)

[image]

7. In action - go to your page

[image]

8. Hit Execute
9. Select Next Scheduled Contribution Date and assign the new value for it (this is the date/time/format that CiviCRM uses):
   **2017-05-01 00:00:00**

   [image]
10. Next and Confirm!
    And check that it worked: it did - will transact on May 01, 2017:

[image]

Comment: code has been pushed to the -dev version available now at the Drupal.org project page, or beta7 when it is released.